# 'Factual matrix' vs. 'Fact pattern'

Tags: canada, legal-terms, england-and-wales

Google revealed [a definition](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Fact+Situation) of 'Fact Pattern/Situation' **(abbreviate to FP)**

> *A concise description of all the occurrences or circumstances of a particular case, without any discussion of their consequences under the law. The fact situation, sometimes referred to as a* **fact  pattern [bold mine]**, *is a summary of what took place in a case* *for which relief is sought. The fact situation of one case is almost always distinguishable from that of another case.*
>
> When one case with a particular fact situation has been decided, an attorney may use it as precedent and relate it to another similar case on which he or she is currently working.

but nothing for ["Factual matrix"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Factual+matrix%22+meaning&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&ei=2ZVAWsSXN4bVwQKVxpDYDg&start=0&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=599), except its use in Canada and England & Wales.

1. So what's the definition of Factual Matrix **(abbreviate to FM)**?
2. Please contrast and compare FM and FP?

Answer (score 1):

The concepts are similar in meaning. It appears from multiple examples, that FM is usually used as a term meaning "all relevant facts that have been found to be present by the trier of fact" while "fact pattern" is used at least as commonly to refer to a diagnostic set of hypothetical facts (much like a doctor might define a "syndrome"), rather than to facts that have been actually found to be present in a particular case. The meaning of FM is closer to the notion of "considering the totality of the evidence", than it is to "fact pattern."