# What is a factual matrix?

Tags: contract-law

How do we identify the requirements of determining what a factual matrix is in relation to answering problems in contract law?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Factual matrix' vs. 'Fact pattern'](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24919/factual-matrix-vs-fact-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

> What is a factual matrix?

The term simply refers to the context and circumstances underlying the controversy. See [*BladeROOM Group Limited v. Emerson Electric Co.*](https://www.leagle.com/decision/infdco20180510927):

> The courts will, in principle, "look at all the circumstances surrounding the making of the contract and available to the parties," otherwise known as the "factual matrix.

See also [*Warner v. Nutrien., LTD.*](https://www.leagle.com/decision/infdco20181213a86):

> this court must give the Plans "their natural and ordinary meaning.[...] That is, "what a reasonable person would have understood from the words of the document[s] read as a whole and from the factual matrix [of their formation].

For additional examples, search for the term in the results retrieved with [this query](http://www.leagle.com/leaglesearch?exact=factual%20matrix).

> How do we identify the requirements of determining what a factual matrix is in relation to answering problems in contract law?

That is a broad question for something that has to be determined on a case-by-case basis. Basically one has to identify the facts that are relevant to the intent, enforceability, effects, etc. of a contract for claims arising from a breach thereof.

An example discussing enforceability of a contract is [*Ecore International Inc. v. Downey*, 343 F.Supp.3d 549, 481, 492 (2018)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/343195792fsupp3d45923):

> the Ontario Court of Appeals reasoned: [...] The wording of the
>   agreements and the **overall factual matrix** reveals that the de facto
>   relationship between the parties was between Ecore and Downey.
>
> The wording of the agreements and the overall factual matrix reveals
>   that the **de facto relationship** between the parties was between Ecore
>   and Downey

(emphasis added).

To determine relevance of circumstances, one can ask himself "*in the absence of this circumstance, would the contract at issue have been any different?*". The more significant the difference, the clearer the grounds for considering that circumstance an element of the factual matrix.